# Simple Ruby Regex for JSON string

Tags: ruby, regex, json

I have the following simple JSON string:

```
{\"exclude\"=>[4, 5, 6, 10], \"include\"=>[]}
```

and I'd like to extract each number in the array following "exclude".  In other words, I'd expect my 0th match to be all numbers, my first match to be 4, my second 5, and so on.  Many thanks.

Comment: I'm confused about two things: **1.** Why would you want to scan JSON with a regex when JSON's entire reason for existence is that every language has already-written parsers for it? **2.** That isn't JSON, it's almost Ruby, it looks like the output of `Kernel#p`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not a single neat regex like you might hope for:

```
s = '{\"exclude\"=>[4, 5, 6, 10], \"include\"=>[]}'

all_numbers = s[/\[[\d,\s]+\]/]
# => "[4, 5, 6, 10]"

all_numbers.scan(/\d+/).map { |m| m.to_i }
# => [4, 5, 6, 10]

# Depends how much you trust the regex that grabs the result for all_numbers.
eval(all_numbers)
# => [4, 5, 6, 10]

# As a one-liner.
s[/\[[\d,\s]+\]/].scan(/\d+/).map { |m| m.to_i } # => [4, 5, 6, 10]
```

Comment: Glad to help. As others have said, look into a JSON parser. Of course you may have some performance considerations we don't know of.

Answer (score 0):

if i really had to use regexps here, i would do something like this:

```
string = "{\"exclude\"=>[4, 5, 6, 10], \"include\"=>[]}"

exclude, include = string.scan(/(\[[\d,\s]{0,}\])/).map {|match| eval match.first}

exclude # => [4, 5, 6, 10]
include # => []
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by DigitalRoss, your String does not contain JSON, but apparently plain Ruby code.

You can easily evaluate it and access it simply:

```
lStr = "{\"exclude\"=>[4, 5, 6, 10], \"include\"=>[]}"

# Evaluate the string: you get a map
lMap = eval(lStr)
# => {"exclude"=>[4, 5, 6, 10], "include"=>[]}

# Read the properties
lMap['exclude']
# => [4, 5, 6, 10]
lMap['include']
# => []
lMap['exclude'][2]
# => 6
```